# Impersonate a membership user in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, impersonation

In a generic `asp.net` website with `Membership`, `Roles` and hashed passwords enabled, I would like to provide the administrators with `impersonation` so that they may browse the website as *that* user would. The website should function as if that user is logged on and then be able to revert to their own login.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

**An example use-case:** A website with two types of users: 'Buyer' and 'Admin'.
The website provides a 'Purchase' button to buy something specifically provided to the user by the admins. i.e only that buyer can use the purchase button and make a payment.
User has trouble so a support admin can 'impersonate' the user's login and purchase on their behalf or 'see' the trouble they are facing.

Without impersonation, the only way is to allow this in code and that negates the purpose of 'seeing the user's issue'. Not even if I was not using hashed passwords and had used `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` and manually logged in the admin as the user.

I hope i am making sense above.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [this sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FormsUserImpersonation.aspx) on codeproject.com. I think it does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the code we used to do this in front of me (assignment from a few years ago), but there are bits in the Membership API to sign someone in using code. I will not have access to the code until this weekend, unfortunately, or I could quickly share the bits and be done with this.

I do remember you had to get the user first, as a MembershipUser, using the Membership class. I am not sure, from this point, whether you had to validate against provider or what.We did use a custom provider, but I forget whether it was related to this solution.

Regardless, examine the security bits, focusing on membership and membershipUser.