# ASP.NET Membership Login as User

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, asp.net-membership, admin

I have an ASP.NET Membership Site with different roles (customer and admin).

Is it possible to login as a customer when i am logged in as an admin? How?

I have no access to the passwords, so i don't know if it is possible or how.

Comment: Do you mean log in as a *specific* user? Or just log in as a user in the `customer` role?

Comment: What kind of ASP.NET authentication do you use: forms, windows, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built-in ASP.NET Membership Provider has not such feature, I would call it "impersonation".

To implement it you need to inherit [SqlMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx) and extend it.

See also:

- [Impersonation using ASP.NET Membership Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833810/asp-net-membership-provider-impersonation)
- [Impersonate a membership user in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836837/impersonate-a-membership-user-in-asp-net)
- https://www.google.com/search?q=impersonation+asp.net+memebship

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about the roles *admin* and *customer*, you can assign both roles to the user.

Comment: the admin should be able to login as a specific customer

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly then this may be an option [forms authentication user impersonation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43724/ASP-NET-Forms-authentication-user-impersonation) - I have implemented it in a production site and works pretty well.